# I want to display a popup message of date contains in excel file

Tags: powershell

I am having a script file to compare the my system login username and samaccountname. If the system login username and samaccountname is matched then my output is display popup message of my system login username. As of now in message box only displaying the login username. Additionally i want display the date which is matching samaccountname row date.

the popup message & excel file data is attached as image file

```
$FilePath = 'd:\Alluserreport.xlsx'
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filepath)

# get data from column 2
$data = $wb.Worksheets['Alluserreport'].UsedRange.Rows.Columns[2].Value2

# cleanup
$wb.close()
$xl.Quit()
While([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb) -ge 0){}
while([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl) -ge 0){} 
Remove-Variable xl,wb # this is optional


If ($data -eq $env:USERNAME )

{
  Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework
                    $msgBody = "$env:USERNAME"
                     $msgTitle = "Test"
                     $msgButton = 'OK'
                     $msgImage = 'Asterisk'
                     $Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)
}
Else {
            Write-Host "Not found"
}
```

Message box output

[image]

Excel data input

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the rows and columns of interest and create an array of objects from it storing both the SamAccountName and the corresponding LastLogonDate like below:

```
$FilePath = 'd:\Alluserreport.xlsx'
$xl = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $false
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open($filepath)

# get data from columns 2 and 3
$sheet = $wb.Worksheets['Alluserreport']
$rowMax = $sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

$data = for ($row = 2; $row -le $rowMax; $row++) {
    [PsCustomObject] @{
        SamAccountName = $sheet.Cells.Item($row, 2).Value2
        LastLogonDate  = [datetime]::FromOADate($sheet.Cells.Item($row, 3).Value2)  # convert to DateTime object
    }
}

# cleanup
$wb.close()
$xl.Quit()
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($wb)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet)
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

# filter for a specific username in the data
$user = $data | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -eq $env:USERNAME }

if ($user) {
    $msgBody   = "User: {0}`r`nLastLogon: {1}" -f $user.SamAccountName, $user.LastLogonDate
    $msgTitle  = "Test"
    $msgButton = 'OK'
    $msgImage  = 'Asterisk'
    $Result    = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)

}
else {
    Write-Host "Not found"
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Theo  I have one another small query i need to add one condition (Like i need to display the message only for lastlogin is geater than 5 days),  I tried the condition like """"$user = $data | Where-Object { ($_.SamAccountName -eq $env:USERNAME) -and ($_.lastloginDate -gt  (Get-Date).AddDays(5) ) }""""

Comment: @Arunkumar If you're looking for a LastLogonDate within the last 5 days, add this to the Where-Object clause: 
`$user = $data | Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -eq $env:USERNAME -and $_.LastLogonDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5).Date }`